# Volume Control iOS

Tags: ios, swift

While I was using snapchat, I noticed that when the volume was changed while playing a video or snap the obtrusive volume box usually in the middle of the screen didn't show and was instead replaced with smaller bars at the top of the screen.

How can I create a similar result (basically, removing the obtrusive volume box from the centre of the screen) for an app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah there are a few workarounds but people are disliking your question because there is not too much information and kind of simple to find the answer to, but nonetheless, this should answer your question.

[Controlling System Output Volume With The MPVolumeView Class (Part 1)](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/controlling-system-output-volume-with-the-mpvolumeview-class-part-one/)

Cheers!